# Invalid column name 'ISBN'

Tags: c#, sql-server

Ive created an update command but it has an error. My code is this.

```
cmd.CommandText = ("UPDATE Penalty SET [Due Date] = '"+ duedate +"' WHERE ISBN = '" + textBox4.Text + "'");
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

it said that Invalid column name 'ISBN' . I cant figure out the error.

Comment: Penalty doesn't have an ISBN column?

Comment: Does the `Penalty` table have an ISBN column?

Comment: String concatenation in sql should generally be avoided, due to the risk of sql injection. Consider using parameterized quieries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This usually really means that there is absolutely no column named `ISBN` in your table `Penalty`.

Check the exact spelling of this column (case usually matters!).

Comment: *case usually matters* Not on MSSQL.

Answer (score 4):

> Invalid column name 'ISBN'

check you have column called 'ISBN' in your `Penalty` table and correct it first.

Then you better move to parameters, if you set `'"+ duedate +"'` date time like that it will consider as string because of `''`

code with parameters

```
cmd.CommandText = ("UPDATE Penalty SET [Due Date] = @duedate WHERE ISBN = @ISBN");
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@duedate",duedate  );
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ISBN",textBox4.Text);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Answer (score 2):

It's telling you that the Penalty table doesn't have a column called ISBN. Without seeing the table definition, it's not really possible to diagnose further. Can you post it?

When you've sorted that issue, read up on SQL Injection attacks. With the code you've posted, a user could easily wreak havoc with your database.